# How to pass a file handle to a function?

Tags: perl

When I run the code below I get

```
Can't use string ("F") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at ./T.pl line 21.
```

where line 21 is

```
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl ':flock', 'SEEK_SET'; # file locking
use Data::Dumper;
# use xx;

my $file = "T.yaml";
my $fh = "F";
my $obj = open_yaml_with_lock($file, $fh);

$obj->{a} = 1;

write_yaml_with_lock($obj, $fh);

sub open_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($file, $fh) = @_;

    open $fh, '+<', $file;
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
    my $obj = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh);

    return $obj;
}

sub write_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($obj, $fh) = @_;

    my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($obj);
    $YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;
    seek $fh,0, SEEK_SET;   # seek back to the beginning of file

    print $fh $yaml . "---\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is using the string "F" as a filehandle.  This
has never been something that's worked; you could use a bareword as a
filehandle (`open FH, ...; print FH ...`), or you could pass in an
empty scalar and perl would assign a new open file object to that
variable.  But if you pass in the string F, then you need to refer to
then handle as `F`, not `$fh`.  But, don't do that.

Do this instead:

```
sub open_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($file) = @_;

    open my $fh, '+<', $file or die $!;
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;

    my $obj = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh); # this dies on failure
    return ($obj, $fh);
}
```

We're doing several things here.  One, we're not storing the
filehandle in a global.  Global state makes your program extremely
difficult to understand -- I had a hard time with your 10 line post --
and should be avoided.  Just return the filehandle, if you want to
keep it around.  Or, you can alias it like `open` does:

```
sub open_yaml_with_lock {
    open $_[0], '+<', $_[1] or die $!;
    ...
}

open_yaml_with_lock(my $fh, 'filename');
write_yaml_with_lock($fh);
```

But really, this is a mess.  Put this stuff in an object.  Make `new`
open and lock the file.  Add a `write` method.  Done.  Now you can
reuse this code (and let others do the same) without worrying about
getting something wrong.  Less stress.

The other thing we're doing here is checking errors.  Yup, disks can
fail.  Files can be typo'd.  If you blissfully ignore the return value
of open and flock, then your program may not be doing what you think
it's doing.  The file might not be opened.  The file might not be
locked properly.  One day, your program is not going to work properly
because you spelled "file" as "flie" and the file can't be opened.
You will scratch your head for hours wondering what's going on.
Eventually, you'll give up, go home, and try again later.  This time,
you won't typo the file name, and it will work.  Several hours will
have been wasted.  You'll die several years earlier than you should
because of the accumulated stress.  So just `use autodie` or write `or
die $!` after your system calls so that you get an error message when
something goes wrong!

Your script would be correct if you wrote `use autodie qw/open flock
seek close/` at the top.  (Actually, you should also check that
"print" worked or use
[File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp) or
`syswrite`, since autodie can't detect a failing `print` statement.)

So anyway, to summarize:

- Don't `open $fh` when `$fh` is defined.  Write `open my $fh` to
    avoid thinking about this.
- Always check the return values of system calls.  Make autodie do
    this for you.
- Don't keep global state.  Don't write a bunch of functions that
    are meant to be used together but rely on implicit preconditions
    like an open file.  If functions have preconditions, put them in
    a class and make the constructor satisfy the preconditions.
    This way, you can't accidentally write buggy code!

**Update**

OK, here's how to make this more OO.  First we'll do "pure Perl" OO
and then use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose).  Moose is
what I would use for any real work; the "pure Perl" is just for the
sake of making it easy to understand for someone new to both OO and
Perl.

```
package LockedYAML;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl ':flock', 'SEEK_SET';
use YAML::Syck;

use autodie qw/open flock sysseek syswrite/;

sub new {
    my ($class, $filename) = @_;
    open my $fh, '+<', $filename;
    flock $fh, LOCK_EX;

    my $self = { obj => YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh), fh => $fh };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub object { $_[0]->{obj} }

sub write {
    my ($self, $obj) = @_;
    my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($obj);

    local $YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1; # ensure that this is
                                            # set for us only

    my $fh = $self->{fh};

    # use system seek/write to ensure this really does what we
    # mean.  optional.
    sysseek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
    syswrite $fh, $yaml;

    $self->{obj} = $obj; # to keep things consistent
}
```

Then, we can use the class in our main program:

```
use LockedYAML;

my $resource = LockedYAML->new('filename');
print "Our object looks like: ". Dumper($resource->object);

$resource->write({ new => 'stuff' });
```

Errors will throw exceptions, which can be handled with
[Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny), and the YAML
file will stay locked as long as the instance exists.  You can, of
course, have many LockedYAML objects around at once, that's why we
made it OO.

And finally, the Moose version:

```
package LockedYAML;
use Moose;

use autodie qw/flock sysseek syswrite/;

use MooseX::Types::Path::Class qw(File);

has 'file' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => File,
    handles  => ['open'],
    required => 1,
    coerce   => 1,
);

has 'fh' => (
    is         => 'ro',
    isa        => 'GlobRef',
    lazy_build => 1,
);

has 'obj' => (
    is         => 'rw',
    isa        => 'HashRef', # or ArrayRef or ArrayRef|HashRef, or whatever
    lazy_build => 1,
    trigger    => sub { shift->_update_obj(@_) },
);

sub _build_fh {
    my $self = shift;
    my $fh = $self->open('rw');
    flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
    return $fh;
}

sub _build_obj {
    my $self = shift;
    return YAML::Syck::LoadFile($self->fh);
}

sub _update_obj {
    my ($self, $new, $old) = @_;
    return unless $old; # only run if we are replacing something

    my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($new);

    local $YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;

    my $fh = $self->fh;
    sysseek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
    syswrite $fh, $yaml;

    return;
}
```

This is used similarly:

```
 use LockedYAML;

 my $resource = LockedYAML->new( file => 'filename' );
 $resource->obj; # the object
 $resource->obj( { new => 'object' }); # automatically saved to disk
```

The Moose version is longer, but does a lot more runtime consistency
checking and is easier to enhance.  YMMV.

Comment: That's incredible! It works =) I really learned a lot from your post! I had no idea that I could do `return ($obj, $fh);` and `open my $fh`. I stripped the error handling on purpose to make the script shorter for the post =) I use Log4Perl's `$logger->error_die()`. But I have no idea how to make it into an object. How would you do that?

Comment: Also, maybe you really want KiokuDB and the File backend instead of this locked YAML file.  KiokuDB will store the data as a YAML file, but will also do transactions so you don't have to do exclusive locking.  Take a look on search.cpan.

Comment: @jrockway : I think itis time for me to go OOP. Thanks for the exceeding good example =)

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
 open FILEHANDLE,EXPR
```

> If FILEHANDLE is an undefined scalar variable (or array or hash
>   element) the variable is assigned a reference to a new anonymous
>   filehandle, otherwise if FILEHANDLE is an expression, its value is
>   used as the name of the real filehandle wanted. (This is considered a
>   symbolic reference, so "use strict 'refs'" should
>   *not* be in effect.)

Filehandle here is an expression ("F") so itsvalue is used as the name of the real filehandle you want.  (A filehandle called F).  And then... the documentation says "use strict 'refs'" should not be in effect, because you're using F as a symbolic reference.

(`use strict;` on line 1 includes `strict 'refs'`.)

Had you just said at the beginning:

```
  my $fh;
```

This would have worked, because then $fh would become a reference to a new anonymous filehandle and Perl won't try to use it as a symbolic reference.

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $global_fh;

open_filehandle(\$global_fh);
use_filehandle(\$global_fh);

sub open_filehandle {
    my ($fh)=@_;

    open($$fh, ">c:\\temp\\testfile") || die;
}

sub use_filehandle {
    my($fh) = @_;

    # Print is pecular that it expects the next token to be the filehandle
    # or a simple scalar.  Thus, print $$fh "Hello, world!" will not work.
    my $lfh = $$fh;
    print $lfh "Hello, world!";   

    close($$fh);
}
```

Or you can do what the other poster suggested and use $_[1] directly, but that's a bit harder to read.

Comment: Added a note on how to fix it.  You can either just pass in an undefined scalar, or turn off strict refs (I don't advise the latter).

Comment: If I change `my $fh = "F";` to `my $fh;` then I get `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./T.pl line 32.` which is the SEEK line.

Comment: You're using the *name* $fh in various places, but they're all independent variables.  Try passing in $fh as a reference (`open_yaml(..., \$fh)`, `write_yaml(..., \$fh)`) instead of a value. Inside of the functions, use `$$fh` to use the local $fh as a scalar reference.  Using program-wide and subroutine variables with the same name is confusing you.

Comment: If I try that, then I get `Not a GLOB reference at ./T.pl line 21.`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the value directly in the sub, it will work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $fh;
yada($fh);
print $fh "testing, testing";

sub yada {
    open $_[0], '>', 'yada.gg';
}
```

Or as a reference:

```
yada(\$fh);

sub yada {
    my $handle = shift;
    open $$handle, '>', 'yada.gg';
}
```

Or better yet, return a filehandle:

```
my $fh = yada($file);

sub yada {
    my $inputfile = shift;
    open my $gg, '>', $inputfile;
    return $gg;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then if fails on `seek $fh,0, SEEK_SET;` with `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./T.pl line 33.`

Comment: I see.. well, if your filehandle is undefined, then your read function is not actually working. Or you are not saving your filehandle properly.

Comment: The problem you are experiencing is that the filehandle you open in the `open` sub is not saved, except in the YAML object. Question is, do you NEED a global filehandle?

Comment: Please don't use symbolic references.  Just store the file object in a scalar and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
my $fh = "F"; # text and also a ref in nonstrict mode
```

with

```
my $fh = \*F; # a reference, period
```

Of course, it's better yet to use lexical filehandles, as in `open my $fd, ... or die ...`, but that's not always possible, e.g. you have `STDIN` that's predefined. In such cases, use `\*FD` wherever `$fd` fits.

*There's also a case with old scripts, you have to watch out where a global FD is opened and closed.*

Comment: Don't do this.  Just use a lexical filehandle!