# perl: paths+dirs array passed byreference to a sub will not print or open correctly

Tags: perl

I need to open and use the contents of files as they are passed as a reference into my subroutine. I have researched and found

[How to pass a file handle to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845376/how-to-pass-a-file-handle-to-a-function)

but this did not work for me.

I have minimized the code considerably to get to the point.  Here it is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dirs = qw(/opt/r2configs/sapbid00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out /opt/r2configs/sapbiq00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out);

sub _ce {

    die "no parameter!\n" unless @_;
    my ($ce_ref) = @_;

    for my $name (@{ $ce_ref }) {
        print "$name\n";
        chomp $name;
        open (my $i, "+<", $name) or warn $!;
        while (<$i>) {
            print "$i,\n";
        }
    }
}

_ce( \@dirs );
```

```
# perl -c foo
foo syntax OK
root@r2nim01.xxx.com(/usr/local/scripts)$
# perl foo
/opt/r2configs/sapbid00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out
GLOB(0x20020148),
GLOB(0x20020148),
GLOB(0x20020148),
GLOB(0x20020148),
GLOB(0x20020148),
/opt/r2configs/sapbiq00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out
GLOB(0x20020148),
GLOB(0x20020148),
.
.
.

### The files do exist and I am root user. ###
# ls -l /opt/r2configs/sapbiq00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system         2217 Mar 15 20:35 /opt/r2configs/sapbiq00/2018/03/15/lparstat-i.out
```

Comment: Have you looked at the preview of your question? Your formatting is all broken. Please pay closer attention next time.

Comment: I did, looked OK.  Thank you for fixing, I am new here.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: It's markdown syntax. There is no need to escape things. Just indent code with four spaces.

Comment: `chomp $name;` makes no sense here. Your filenames don't contain trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (<$i>) {
        print "$i,\n";
    }
```

Here you are printing the filehandle for each line in the file.  Print the line you read instead:

```
print "$_,\n";
```

Better yet:

```
while (my $line = <$i>) {
    print "$line,\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, a function that implicitly modifies a global variable like `$_` is naughty.

Comment: Yes you are so correct.  Thank you as well @ysth @melpomene!

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting the file handle, not the content.

```
while (<$i>) {
    print "$i,\n"; # <--- here
}
```

`$i` is the handle. Since you're reading without a variable, you need to look at `$_`.

```
print "$_,\n"; # <--- here
```

---

You might also want to name your handle `$fh` as per the convention. `$i` is typically used for a `for` loop iteration variable that counts something.

Comment: OmG, duh!  Thank you Sim!  Yes printing $_ is what I wanted.